# White Screen of Death Debugging Tips for PHP Code

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I am recieving a white screen for my wordpress site. Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method APCu_Object_Cache::incr2() in /home/content/a2pewpnaspod04_data05/06/41366906/html/wp-content/object-cache.php on line 240

Here is the code around line 240:

```
 function wp_cache_add( $key, $data, $group = '', $expire = 0 ) {
    global $wp_object_cache;

    if ( 'transient' == $group ) {
        wpaas_save_transient( $key, $data, $expire );

        return $wp_object_cache->add( "_transient_$key", $data, 'options', $expire );
    } elseif ( 'site-transient' == $group ) {
        wpaas_save_transient( $key, $data, $expire, true );

        return $wp_object_cache->add( "_site_transient_$key", $data, 'site-options', $expire );
    } else {
        return $wp_object_cache->add( $key, $data, $group, $expire );
    }
}

function wp_cache_incr( $key, $n = 1, $group = '' ) {
    global $wp_object_cache;

    return $wp_object_cache->incr2( $key, $n, $group );
}

function wp_cache_decr( $key, $n = 1, $group = '' ) {
    global $wp_object_cache;

    return $wp_object_cache->decr( $key, $n, $group );
}

function wp_cache_close() {
    return true;
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: the method you trying to call i undefined, that's the problem

Comment: Have you had a caching plugin previously enabled but since disabled it (and it didn't clean up and remove the object-cache.php)? Rename the object-cache.php to get back into the system, then investigate.